# Problem with getting handrail flange bracket tight to post

Tags: handrail

[image]I am mounting a handrail to some steps and the bottom concrete area below the steps. I am having an issue with getting the set screws to tighten to the metal post that goes into the flange bracket. I have included a picture of the flange bracket. It will tighten but with very little back and forth movement it becomes loose again. Two set screws to flange.Only on side seen.  Any suggestions?

Here is what the bracket itself looks like including the two corner set screws:

[image]

Comment: A picture with your post with mount would be helpful, this bracket does not look like it is intended for what you are using it for. Too small of base to get any strength for a newel post. It looks more like a decorative base.

Comment: I have added a picture of post and base as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am inclined to agree with Jack in the initial comments here that the bracket shown is what not going to ever be able to constrain the post to no movement. At best the depth of engagement of the post into the bracket is about two inches and the total length of the post is probably about 36 to 40 inches. Think of the size of lever arm at play here. It is very easy to see how even moderate pressure on the post could deform the bottom portion. This would be even more true if the post itself is relatively thin material.

Even if the post were literally welded to the bracket any racking of the post would likely experience problems with the relatively small studs that you have embedded into the concrete.

You will have to find a way to secure the upper end of the post in such manner as to constrain it from movement. This will undoubtedly be taken care of in a direction that is inline with railing assembly once things are fully assembled. Racking of the post in a direction that is at right angles to the railing will require additional measures. Some possible options:

1. If the upper portion of the railing is adjacent to the building structure use another type of bracket to bolt the upper portion of the post to the building.
2. If there is additional span of the base concrete about 12 to 18 inches from the post on the side away from where you walk you could attach another bracket to the concrete and secure a bar or rail from there at an angle up about half  the way up the post. This will create a strong triangular structure to prevent the racking. It even looks as if Lowes sells a  bracket made for just this purpose:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try drilling holes in the vertical member for the set screws to engage. Remove the setscrews and drill a hole that is smaller than the set screw shaft that the end of the set screw will engage. You need not drill a hole all the way through--just make a pocket for the end of the screw to fit in.

Right now the screw is contacting the corner of the vertical post and this is a small area engagement which gets loose.